# How to combine command substitution and regex?

Tags: regex, bash, find, command-substitution

Is there a possibility to do command substitution in a regex?
I want to find files in Linux with specific names. The name may include fix strings, but it may also only include the hostname.
So what i want to do is something like:

```
find /home/ -type f -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*(string1|string2|`hostname`).*'
```

I'm not sure whether it's possible to somehow concat the output of the hostname command with the regex?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :

```
find /home/ -type f -regextype posix-extended -regex ".*(string1|string2|$HOSTNAME).*"
```

if you need to use a command instead :

```
find /home/ -type f -regextype posix-extended -regex ".*(string1|string2|$(hostname)).*"
```